# Explanation about proof that $A \cap(B-C)$ = $(A\cap B)-(A\cap C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

*The question is...*

> **For sets $A$, $B$ and $C$ using properties of sets, prove that:**
>
> **$A \cap(B-C)$ = $(A\cap B)-(A\cap C)$**

*And the answer is this....*

> **Step 1 ---> $A  \cap (B-C)$=$A \cap (B \cap C') ........... [\because  B-C=B \cap C'$]**
>
> **Step 2 ---> $(A \cap B) \cap C'$**
>
> **Step 3---> $\emptyset\cup ((A \cap B) \cap C')$**
>
> **Step 4 ---> $((A \cap B) \cap A') \cup ((A \cap B) \cap C')....  [\because (A \cap B) \cap A'= \emptyset]$**
>
> **Step 5 --->$(A \cap B) \cap (A' \cup C')$**
>
> **Step 6 --->$(A \cap B) \cap (A \cap C)'$**
>
> **Step 7 ---> $(A \cap B) - ( A \cap C)$**

- *What I can't understand here is that what was the need to introduce $\emptyset$ in the answer?*
- *Isn't there any other way to solve this question?*

*I approached this question like this...*

> $A \cap (B-C) = A \cap (B \cap C')$
>
> $(A \cap B) \cap (A \cap C')$
>
> $(A \cap B) \cap (A-C)$

*That's it. I am stuck after this. What to do?*

Comment: Your title was one of the worst ever, please study the revised version.

Comment: @Did Sir I apologize for my mistake. I tried to post the question the way you have posted it now but I don't know what went wrong and I was not able to post the question. So I simply wrote "Help proving this question". Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start at the second line of your approach.

Note that $(A\cap B)\cap(A\cap C^{\complement})=A\cap B\cap A\cap C^{\complement}=A\cap B\cap C^{\complement}=(A\cap B)-C\tag1$

This on base of associativity of $\cap$ and $A\cap A=A$.

However what "they" want to see as outcome is $(A\cap B)-(A\cap C)$, which is the same as the RHS of $(1)$ of course.

This can be reached by realizing that $A\cap B\cap A^{\complement}=\varnothing$ so that: $$A\cap B\cap C^{\complement}=(A\cap B\cap A^{\complement})\cup(A\cap B\cap C^{\complement})=(A\cap B)\cap(A^{\complement}\cup C^{\complement})=$$$$(A\cap B)\cap(A\cap C)^{\complement}=(A\cap B)-(A\cap C)$$

Comment: Sir the answer was really helpful. But how will I realize that I need to 'union' ( A $\cap$ B $\cap$  A') with (A $\cap$  B $\cap$ C') to arrive at the desired answer? Is there any alternative to the above answer?

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively:
$$(A \cap B) \cap (A \cap C')=(A \cap B) \cap (A \cap (A\cap C)')=$$
$$((A\cap B)\cap A)\cap (A\cap C)'=(A\cap B)\cap(A\cap C)'=(A\cap B)-(A\cap C).$$